# .pyc file closes immediately

Tags: python, compilation

I am using this code to convert .py file into .pyc

```
import py_compile
import os
import glob

path = ''
for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.py') ):
    print(f"current file is: {infile}")
    strDestination = 'compiled/' + infile + 'c'
    py_compile.compile(infile,strDestination)
```

I converted 6 similar scripts, that uses:
*pandas, calendar, datetime, gc, numpy ,multiprocessing* modules. However, when I try to execute .pyc files, 3 one them work fine and 3 of them closes immediately.

I try to add an ***`input()`*** at the start and the end of the code, but it also closes immediately.

If I execute the same script .py, it works normally.

When the conversion occurs, is it necessary to avoid some specific library ?

**#### UPDATE**

I noticed if I change the name of the .pyc file to the same name of the one that worked, it works. However, it needs to be on the directory folder. Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer: **.pyc File name cannot have special characters.**

I hope this help someone.